# Type 'EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY' could not be resolved error while constant is clearly defined

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, egl

I'm working on a native activity app for Android 2.3.3. I've copied the code from the code samples, I have include paths set, but Eclipse (Indigo) still can't find this constant.

```
EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY); //Type 'EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY' could not be resolved
```

However the compiler shows no error:

```
Compile++ thumb  : NativeTest <= NativeTest.cpp
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 8):

This error has to do with Eclipse not having __ ANDROID__ defined which makes it not define EGLNativeDisplayType in EGL/eglplatform.h which causes EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY to also not be defined.

To fix this go to your projects properties and go to the "C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols" page, under the "Symbols" tab click on GNU C and then the "Add" button and put

```
__ANDROID__
```

in the name feild and click OK. You can do the same for GNU C++.

Comment: I am not getting the "Symbols" tab under "C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols". What to do now ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also just add:

```
 typedef void* EGLNativeDisplayType;
```

before including egl.h.

Comment: Why I need to do this if `egl.h` contains the same definition?